# How to pass one or multiple variables to a newly created thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm learning about threads now. I'm wondering if it is possible to pass a variable to my thread. My assignement is to create a thread and assign a number (a name if you will) to each thread and print the number every 100ms. my current program is as below :

```
#define PCHECK(sts,msg) if((sts)!=0){printf("error : %s\n",msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE)}
#define NB_THREAD 5

void* do_nothing(void* data)
{
    int i;

    //printf("creation thread %d",(int)data);
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(100000);
    printf("thread number : %d \n",data);
    }
    i = 0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);   
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid, j, status;
    pthread_t thread;
    int * res;
    int stat;

    for (j = 0; j < NB_THREAD; j++)
    {
        stat = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_nothing, (void *) j );
        if (stat !=0)
        {
            perror ("pthread_create()");
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < NB_THREAD; j++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread, (void **) &res );
    }



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

for the moment the only number getting printed is 0 (the value of data). Can someone point out where did i went wrong thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good examples of how to pass arguments to pthreads

[1] https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments

Comment: many thanks, this link is very helpful, covers everything about threads. Gonna have a easier time with my lessons now :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem might be that your running this on a 64-bit system that uses 32-bit `int` types. So `data` is a 64-bit `void*` type but in your thread function you're printing it out as a 32-bit `int`:

```
// example assumes that this thread instance was started by
//   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_nothing, (void *) j ) when
//   j == 1

printf("thread number : %d \n",data);
                         ^       ^
                         |       +--------  passing a 64-bit pointer 0x00000000.00000001
                         |
                         +----------------  treats the pointer argument as a 32-bit int and
                                            happens to only see the all-zero 32-bits
```

I suspect that you'll get the output you expect if you change the `printf()` to:

```
printf("thread number : %d \n", (int) data);
```

As a general rule, when writing thread functions I think it's a good idea to have the first actions of the thread function be to convert the data item passed to the thread function to the type that was actually passed to `pthread_create()`:

```
void* do_nothing(void* data)
{
    int id = (int) data; // `pthread_create()` was passed an `int`
                         //    `data` is not used again after this point

    // ...
}
```

A few other points

- if you pass an actual pointer to data to the thread function, make sure that each thread gets their own separate copy (unless the data is supposed to be the same instance for each thread, which is possible but uncommon).
- if you're spinning up multiple threads you either need to keep each `pthread_t` object returned by `pthread_create()` (in an array, maybe) so you can join on them later, or you need to call `pthread_join()`/`pthread_detach()` before reusing the `pthread_t` object so that the system can clean up any resources it has allocated for that thread when the thread finished running. In the example as posted that might not matter much because the threads will run forever (or until something kills the process).  The `pthread_join()` call you have will never complete successfully.

  But the following code is destined to break when you change things so the thread function stops after some amount of time:

  ```
  for (j = 0; j < NB_THREAD; j++)
  {
      pthread_join(thread, (void **) &res );
  }
  ```

  Because `thread` only has the `pthread_t` for the last thread created, once it successfully joins it's not valid to use any more. The next loop iteration will try to join a thread that's already been joined and is no longer valid.